# use angular ui-router views with angular ui-bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

my current code:

```
function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('someState', {
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'my_root_template.html'
      },
      'someNestedView@someState': {
        templateUrl: 'some_nested_view.html'
      }
    }
  })
}
```

now I just open modal dialog from one controller

```
function SomeControler(ModalService) {
  ...
  return ModalService.openModal({
    templateUrl: 'modal_dialog_template_where_root_template_will_be_injected.html',
    controller: 'ModalController'
  });
  ...
}
```

and do state transition in controller which handles the modal itself

```
function ModalController($state) {
  $state.go('someState')
}
```

what I actually don't want to do.

What I want is just use `ui-sref="someState"` in my main menu template to open modal and continue with this approach inside modal dialog - use substates of `someState` to dynamically change content of modal dialog. So, first part is achievable

```
function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('someState', {
    onEnter:     onSomeStateEnter
  })
}

function onSomeStateEnter() {
  ModalService.openModal({
    templateUrl: 'modal_dialog_template_where_root_template_will_be_injected.html',
    controller: 'ModalController'
  });
}
```

but when I'm trying to add some views to that

```
function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('someState', {
    onEnter:     onSomeStateEnter,
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'my_root_template.html'
      },
      'someNestedView@someState': {
        templateUrl: 'some_nested_view.html'
      }
    }
  })
}
```

it opens only modal dialog template, but views are injected to main page (there's also is empty `<ui-view/>`).

What I'm doing wrong? Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use state to open a dialog. If you are using dialog it's only because you don't want to redirect the user to do specific action. I think it's better if you expose in your $scope a function that open your dialog ( in $rootScope if you want to open it every where ).

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure I wanna use state to open dialog and "expose in your $scope" is something what I exactly do right now, and want to get rid of that. This example is just abstract and simplified thing and in reality mixing logic of opening modal dialog with business logic in controller become a real pain and I need somehow to put it "under the hood". Same for logic of state transitions inside modal dialog. My idea is to make it transparent for one who designing templates (as these are different persons who creates controllers and who creates templates)

Comment: I can't post it as an answer to my question - I'm not pretty sure I'm right, but after some unsuccessful googling I found that for now it's not possible. There is [feature request](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2400) in ui-router library issue tracker already made by most active one of ui-bootstrap contributors [Weseley Cho](https://github.com/wesleycho). As far as I understood this is the reason why I can't inject my views - there's no view where to inject. Opening modal is async operation and it's not resolved at the moment I'm trying to inject.